# Sending and receiving fax with sharepoint

Tags: development, workflow

my clients expressed the need to be able to send faxes from sharepoint.

So they would open up a web page somewhere on the intranet, they would then select another company and click on a send button. This would send a fax to the said company using a template already in sharepoint.

But they would also like to get notified when they get fax responses.

I started looking around and i saw that MS already as a a small fax library, FaxComLib. I just need to know if its possible to implement FaxComLib with a fax server to be able to get notification of incoming faxes and sending some.

I also need a fax server, is there some way i can rent either a fax server or some web services i can call to get it to work ???

Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you looked into GFI Fax Maker?

or for a full solution and to change yourself you could use:

http://www.concordfax.com/microsoft/sharepoint.aspx

http://developer.concordfax.com/

also another two big companies that are used alot are Viscendo, biscom fax servers.

I think someone wanted to do somthing similar to you aswell:

http://www.linkedin.com/answers/technology/enterprise-software/TCH_ENT/472044-37931110

As for faxconlib i wouldnt know tbh but there is the documentation here if you got the time :) http://www.interfax.net/en/dev/faxcomexlib

hope this is some help to you :)

Comment: I still see the need for a fax server program like GFI faxmaker that probably emails the fax to a mail enabled document library, then set alerts on the document library